# Save a WPF control to PDF using printvisual

Tags: wpf, pdf

Saving a WPF page to a pdf is simple

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), "Microsoft Print to PDF");
printDialog.PrintVisual(grid, "PrintDocument");
```

BUT I would like the pdf document saved to a predifined path without using the dialogbox
Is there an issue

Comment: Sharpening question: [PrinterSettings.PrintFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in PrintDialog.PrintVisual.

Comment: @dovid It's not for WPF.